# missing nvidia-xconfig

Tags: nvidia

I'm trying to install an nvidia driver for my graphics card (optimus unfortunately), and the instructions I have say to run `nvidia-xconfig`. But I don't seem to have it. Earlier I did

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

just to make sure I was starting from scratch. I'm afraid I may have wiped **nvidia-xconfig** that way.

Now, even though I may reinstall **nvidia-common** and **nvidia-settings**, I still can't seem to get **nvidia-xconfig**.

How do I get it?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the `nvidia-xconfig` comes with the driver. Therefore, on my 14.04 system I can search for the command in the packages

```
dpkg -S nvidia-xconfig
```

and I get

> nvidia-331-updates: /usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/bin/nvidia-xconfig

As you see `nvidia-xconfig` is in the package the provides the driver. Which one do you want to install and how?